# Pentaho ETL job not running successfully

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi, spoon

I created Pentaho ETL job which contains two transformations.
inside each transformations i am calling oracle stored procedure.
when i ran the job first time it got completed successfully, but from next time onwards its not moving to next second transformation, still showing execution at first transformation only. when i checked session details in database there is no active sessions.

Comment: Please edit your question to add [**sample data**](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. 
Provide them as [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and strictly [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). 
**DO NOT** post code or additional information in comments. 
Please ensure you have a [**minimal, complete and verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It smells like an autolock. Do you have the same table in an input step and in an output step ?

Comment: Hi Alain, in Transformation there is no input step and output step, just calling the different stored procedures using "call db procedure" step in both transformations as sp1 in transformation 1 and sp2 in transformation 2. first transformation calling the sp1 and data loaded into final tables. My problem is after execution of sp1 its not moving to transformation 2 some times and there is no autolocks or deadlocks in tables.